# Is there a way in chef to provide a value to command prompt?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I am writing a chef code.  I have to run a command which gives me a prompt and then i need to provide a value for the prompt and continue.

Ex :

```
execute 'runTest' do
        command 'test create user'
        action :run
     end
```

Above is just an example.  when i run this code, it gives me a prompt to provide a value.  But i dont know how to do this.  Does any one know how i can implement this in code ?

Comment: IMO, your *shouldn't* do this ... because it means that your recipe won't run unless there is a user present.  Also, asking the user for something means that the running the recipe is not repeatable: the user may give different input each time.

Comment: This is just an example.  Which i am trying to explain.  I want to write chef code for command prompt.

Comment: @StephenC ok, do know what alternative works best?

Comment: @StephenC I read the question differently. I think the Chef recipe is prompting him for input and he needs Chef to provide a value for the recipe to complete. Insomiac, could you clarify and maybe provide a clearer example?

Answer (score 0):

You should have the user inputs in attributes, so that you can change it easily whenever needed and you can override from roles or in other places.
You recipe has to be written in a way to get values from attributes and process it.